# What is up with these estimates from Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to get a reach estimate for:

```
"geo_locations" => array("geo_markets" => array("name"=>"Norfolk")),
"age_min" => 18,
"age_max" => 18,
```

This results in results that look like this:

```
    Array
(
    [users] => 23000
    [bid_estimations] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [unsupported] => 
                    [location] => 3
                    [reach_min] => 0
                    [reach_max] => 0
                    [cpm_curve_data] => 
                    [cpc_curve_data] => 
                    [cpa_curve_data] => 
                    [dedup_winning_rate] => 0
                    [dedup_status] => 0
                    [pacing_status] => 0
                    [account_budget] => 150000
                    [estimate_DAU] => 0
                    [bid_amount_min] => 104
                    [bid_amount_median] => 261
                    [bid_amount_max] => 411
                )

        )

    [estimate_ready] => 1
)
```

These bid amounts look extremely high. Are these in dollars or cents?

Comment: I'd open a ticket at FB if the documentation isn't enough clear on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These amounts (account_budget,bid_amount_min,bid_amount_median,bid_amount_max) are in cents

You can read out more about Facebook currencies

[Facebook currencies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/currencies)